# How can I model the following scenario using a single primary key instead of a compound primary key?

Tags: sql, django

Suppose I am modelling an athletics event.  The primary key would be date, track and race_no.

```
class Event(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    race_no = models.IntegerField()     
    track = models.CharField(max_length = 4)
    temperature = models.IntegerField()

class Race(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    race_no = models.IntegerField()     
    track = models.CharField(max_length = 4)
    athlete_id = models.ForeignKey(Athlete)
    finishing_pos = models.IntegerField()
```

Now suppose I wish to provide a form for users to look up a particular event.  They will input the date, race_no and track.  Now in the results I wish to provide the event results along with the temperature.  Normally this would be trivial with SQL JOINs. Django at the moment does not have a lot of support for compound keys.  How can I model this use case with a single auto incrementing primary key, which would be much more Django friendly.

Answer (score 2):

Use `unique_together`. 
This way you can have incrementing ids on everything but when they are put together they form a unique key.

You define the `unique_together` in the class' Meta class.

```
class Race(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    race_no = models.IntegerField()     
    track = models.CharField(max_length = 4)
    athlete_id = models.ForeignKey(Athlete)
    finishing_pos = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("date", "race_no", "track")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a  ["Surrogate key"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key), i dont know 'django', but not the point, when ever a date changes because of bad weather, you will get a problem with your database (prob not with django framework), the point is never use probably changing attributes as (or inside a PK)